# Add List as value in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to add a list as value in Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame() 

temp = {'index' : '15054',
        'Titel': 'Tsjechisch',
        'Woorden': '1314',
        'Secties': '5',
        'Namen_Secties': [u'== Alfabet ==\n', u'== Structuur ==\n', u'== Geschiedenis van het Tsjechisch ==\n', u'== Zie ook ==\n', u'== Externe links ==\n']
        }

pd.DataFrame(temp)
```

The problem, as can be seen below is that the variables of the list each get printed as a new row in my dataframe. I actually want this dataframe to be only one row with the list as one variable in the column names_secties

```
    Names_Secties                      Secties  Title   Words       index
0   == Alfabet ==\n                      5  Tsjechisch  1314        15054
1   == Structuur ==\n                    5  Tsjechisch  1314        15054
2   == Geschiedenis van het Tsjechisch ==\n     5   Tsjechisch  1314    15054
3   == Zie ook ==\n                      5  Tsjechisch  1314        15054
4   == Externe links ==\n                5  Tsjechisch  1314    15054
```

Answer (score 2):

Need another `[]` for nested list:

```
temp = {'index' : '15054',
        'Titel': 'Tsjechisch',
        'Woorden': '1314',
        'Secties': '5',
        'Namen_Secties': [[u'== Alfabet ==\n', u'== Structuur ==\n']]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(temp)
print (df)
                          Namen_Secties Secties       Titel Woorden  index
0  [== Alfabet ==\n, == Structuur ==\n]       5  Tsjechisch    1314  15054
```